# Combine multiple models in a Rails form to create a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have two models, Story and Category. Using the form for `Story#new`, I'd like to be able to save the foreign key for Category.

To display the selection data from Category on the `Story#new` form page I've used:

`<%= collection_select(:category , :category, Category.all , :id, :category, {:prompt => 'Select Category...'}) %>`

How can I save `category_id` to the newly created Story object?

---

Story has attributes: `industry_id` and `user_id`, Category has attribute `name`
development.log tells me this: (it looks like it's trying to add a new category (99) to the Categories table

```
Started POST "/stories" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-10 17:32:56 -0600
 Processing by StoriesController#create as HTML
story"=>{"industry_id"=>"8", "user_id"=>"8"}, "category"=>{"category"=>"99"}, "commit"=>"Create Story"}
```

Comment: Does Story `belongs_to` Category? How are the associations laid out?

Comment: yup: `class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :industries
  has_many :categories` and `class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :story`

Comment: so yah actually story has_many categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the parameters to `collection_select`. The first parameter is the name of the model. The second parameter is the name of the model attribute that the value will be assigned to. The fourth parameter is the method of the `Category` object to use as the text value of the select option.

I believe it should look like this:

```
<%= collection_select(:story , :category_id, Category.all , :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Select Category...'}) %>
```

You might also want to look at [ActiveRecord nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: That was the exact answer, thank you Brandan! I was still saving it to the Category model because the first argument was `:category`